# C# Copy xml file from resources to disk

Tags: c#

I tried `File.WriteAllBytes` and some other I just want to copy a xml file from resources to disk just locate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.File.Copy(fromPath, toPath, true)
```

This is assuming your have access to both file paths